# Virtual PC running MS-DOS 6.22 cannot boot SEAL GUI

Tags: virtual-machine, ms-dos

I just don't understand this. I just don't know why SEAL doesn't work... :(

Here is the error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seal2 is a 32-bit GUI and DOS 6.22 is a 16-bit OS.  Try it in FreeDOS 1.1, MS-DOS 7, or Caldera/Dr. DOS, and you should have better results.